# Scaling a variable before passing it by reference

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a C++ project, and I have run into a problem I've had some issue figuring out.

My project is a physical simulator, and I have kept all my conventions in SI units. Due to this, I have ended up with a few parameters that are relatively small relative to 1, on the order of 0.00000001 or so.

I have incorporated a simple control GUI with an outside library (Dear ImGui specifically), and the precision of some of the controls only go to 3 decimal points. The functions to run these controls ask me to pass a pointer to the value, which poses some problems with the small parameters.

I was hoping that there was some way I could pass something like how a C# property works, where for a variable x, I pass a reference to a property which has a get value of "return scale*x", and a set value of "x = value / scale". So then I can set a scale value which transforms the SI units into more human readable ones.

Does anyone have a good suggestion for how I should handle this? I've been scratching my head, and I hope I don't need to save an additional value for each parameter, then constantly update the true values.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Specifically, the slider function is used as follows:
`ImGui::SliderFloat("Label", &myFloat);`, where the value of myFloat is both displayed and changed by the slider.

SECOND EDIT: Never mind, this isn't needed. See comment below.

Comment: Depends mostly on what the `value` type you're passing a pointer to is.  If it is a class type, you can make that class (effectively) a property which recomputes as needed.  If it is a primitive type (such as `int`), then that won't work.  The question is, how does the display library determine what to display from this (abstract?) value type.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, the type is a primitive, specifically float.

Comment: "The functions to run these controls ask me to pass a pointer" would you put in your question the prototype of one of such functions? Can they change the passed value?

Comment: If I had to do this in a modern context, I would personally take inspiration from [std::chrono::duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), but that's not for the faint of heart.

Comment: @MatG good question, I have added an edit.

Comment: Looks like I should've read the documentation better before posting. There is an additional argument I had missed which takes a format string for input. I simply set that to show scientific notation. Thank you to everyone who helped out.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I should've read the documentation better before posting. There is an additional argument I had missed which takes a format string for input. I simply set that to show scientific notation. Thank you to everyone who helped out!